# Selenium How to get text from notification pop up

Tags: java, selenium, automation, notifications

Please see below image. This pink color pop up appears for a second and that automatically disappears. How to get text from this pop up in selenium.

It wont stay on screen and disappears with in a second.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hKytq.jpg)

Comment: Please click on link to view image.

Comment: Your code trials?

Comment: You have to do window handles in selenium

Answer (score 0):

> It wont stay on screen and disappears with in a second.

It seems your problem is that the popup is not staying on screen for enough time to let you identify html elements to use in your selenium script.

If I'm correct, you can press F8 whenever this message appears to pause the chrome window and then normally identify elements from this message. (using F12: Dev tools)

Depending on the message box, you can use:

1. If it is alert/popup. You can use:

```
Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
String text = alert.getText();
```

2. If its html just another html element, like div or td. you can use following:

```
String text= driver.findElement(By.xpath(elementXpath)).getText();
```

Hope this helps!